# All my (jQuery UI) single sliders get the same value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, switch-statement, sliders

I want each slider of the same page have it's own value when I slide each one of them.

When I slide one of them, the "slider block" of each slider works as planned as the conditional background-color, but the value is the same for all the sliders.

Here's my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider').slider({
    value: 5,
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( ".ui-slider-handle" ).text(ui.value);
      switch(ui.value){
        case 1: { $(this).css('background', 'darkred'); break;}
        case 2: { $(this).css('background', 'red'); break;}
        case 3: { $(this).css('background', 'orange'); break;}
        case 4: { $(this).css('background', 'gold'); break;}
        case 5: { $(this).css('background', 'yellow'); break;}
        case 6: { $(this).css('background', '#AAFF00'); break;}
        case 7: { $(this).css('background', 'lime'); break;}
        case 8: { $(this).css('background', 'cyan'); break;}
        case 9: { $(this).css('background', '#00AAFF'); break;}
        case 10: { $(this).css('background', 'blue'); break;}
      }
    }
  });
  $(".ui-slider-handle").val($('.slider').slider( "value" ));
});
```

And here's the code in JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arkl1te/Wrq3H/

Is there a way to fix that? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that they have the same value, the problem is that you're updating both handles each time that a slide occurs. Possible fix: http://jsfiddle.net/Wrq3H/3/

```
//change text for current's slider handle only
        $(this).children(".ui-slider-handle").text(ui.value);
```

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how much time did I waste thinking about the outside part of the switch area... xD

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate value parameter for each slider. They are referencing the same variable and therefore the step is being applied to both based on the latest value. Try something like:

```
valueone = 5,
valuetwo = 5,
/* ... other content ... */

$(".ui-slider-handle").val($('#slider-1').slider( "valueone" ));
$(".ui-slider-handle").val($('#slider-2').slider( "valuetwo" ));
```

Comment: And how about having for example 100 sliders in one page? By you, he need to write the same line of code for every slide, it's not flexible

Comment: Yes, this solution is not elegant. Use the children method mentioned by others

Comment: Thanks for your intention anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

In function for slide you need to change your selector from all elements with `".ui-slider-handle"` to children in element which raises slide event:

```
$(this).children( ".ui-slider-handle" ).text(ui.value);
```

That fix will allow you to use many sliders without changing function for slide
Example http://jsfiddle.net/cVUp3/1/