# Jquery UI two sliders on same page

Tags: jquery, slider, sliders

i have two jquery ui sliders on the same page, with different value ranges, but when i change one, the other one changes also, even when they have different variables, I would like them not to affect each other, so when i make one sliders value bigger or smaller, the other slider wouldn't change

```
 var sliderTooltipAge = function(event, ui) {
    var curValue = ui.value || initialValueAge;
    var tooltip_age = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner">' + curValue + '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';

    $('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip_age);

}
    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      step: 1,
      value: 25,
      min: 18,
      max: 65,
      create: sliderTooltipAge,
      slide: sliderTooltipAge,

    });

};


function slider_sum() {
       var initialValue = 20000;

var sliderTooltip_sum = function(event, ui) {
    var curValue2 = ui.value || initialValue;
    var tooltip_sum = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner">' + curValue2 + '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';

    $('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip_sum);

}
    $( "#slider-range-loan" ).slider({

    value: initialValue,
    min: 20000,
    max: 1000000,
    step: 1000,
    create: sliderTooltip_sum,
    slide: sliderTooltip_sum
    });
  };
```

HTML

```
 <div id="slider-range-loan"></div> 
  <div id="slider-range-min"></div>
```

Comment: Hope it will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680870/all-my-jquery-ui-single-sliders-get-the-same-value?rq=1  .. but please make a more search before asking your question..you will find your answer somewhere in stackoverflow .. Good luck

Comment: The problem is, that my slider uses different min max values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first and second  $('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip_age);

to

$('#slider-range-min .ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip_age);

and

$('#slider-range-loan .ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip_sum);

respectively.

Is that what you're expecting?